# Howto use ipython test on Ubuntu or Debian

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, ipython

I have installed ipython and ipython3 purely with apt-get. No conda or pip were involved. The program iptest did not end in a bin-directory.

```
type iptest
bash: type: iptest: not found
```

The file iptest.py can be found in the directories

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/testing

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/testing

According to the docstring the program should be started with `iptest all`. But the command

```
ipython3 iptest.py all
```

results in the error message

ERROR: Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'all')

How do I correctly use iptest on Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: please show me `echo $PATH` and `echo $PYTHONPATH` and  `env` add it to your question

Comment: do you have this file  ? `/usr/bin/ipython3`

Comment: Yes, I do have '/usr/bin/ipython3'.

Comment: PATH:
/disk2/myname/ccp4/arp_warp_8.0/bin/bin-x86_64-Linux:/disk2/myname/ccp4/ccp4-7.0/etc:/disk2/myname/ccp4/ccp4-7.0/bin:/disk2/myname/ccp4/ccp4-7.0/bin/:/usr/local/xd-distr/bin:/usr/local/utrecht/bin:/usr/local/dectris/albula/3.2/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: PYTHONPATH: empty

Comment: env:
longer than the allowed number of characters for the comment section, here.